# Как правильно импортировать JQuery.cookie. Ошибка $.cookie is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть два файла: index.html и auth.js. В html подключаю библиотеку jquery.cookie.js и она работает, а в другом импортируемом скрипте, auth.js, нет. Объясните, что я делаю не так

index.html:

```
<script src="js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

/* Чтение кукис работает */
<script>
    var token = $.cookie('token');
    console.log(token);
</script>

/* подключаю свой модуль, который тоже использует jquery.cookie.js */
<script src="js/auth.js"></script>
```

auth.js:

```
/* Запись кукис не работает */
function mySetCookie() {
    /* вижу ошибку $.cookie is not a function" */
    /* подозреваю что неверно импортировал, а в чем ошибка не догадываюсь */
    $.cookie('token', 'my_cookie');
}
```

PS.

- На гитхабе jquery.cookie.js был, не помогло.
- На англоязычном стаковерфлоу понял, что плохо импортирую, как хорошо импортировать не понял

Comment: а если:
`var x = $.cookie();
console.log(x);` посмотреть, что вообще туда попадает ?

Comment: Ваш вопрос навел меня на мой ответ. Я уже разобрался в чем дело. Я импортировал на одной странице, а проверял на другой... Банальность:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Напишу ответ для тех, кто наступит на те-же грабли. Если ваш js-модуль, который использует какую-то библиотеку используется на нескольких страницах, проверьте, что эта библиотека подключена на всех страницах.

В моем случае я подключил библиотеку jquery.cookie.js на странице index.html, а проверял это все дело на странице landing.html.

Эта ошибка стала возможна, потому что jquery.cookie.js используется в модуле auth.js, который подключен и к index.html и к landing.html